# join without a join in PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have code with the following `psql` query that I try to understand (It was simplified for the question):

```
select id, time, t.type, t.sub_type from TABLE_A r,TABLE_B t,TABLE_C l where r.type = t.type and t.type = l.type
```

Is it the same as doing a join, or am I missing something here?

Comment: It is an archaic way of writing a `JOIN` and should be replaced.

Comment: Please use modern `JOIN` syntax, not the old syntax from 1989 (the year of the lambada).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing an old school *implicit* join.  This is the syntax used before the ANSI-92 SQL standard which started recommending explicit joins like this version of your query:

```
select id, time, t.type, t.sub_type    -- but please always use aliases here
from TABLE_A r
inner join TABLE_B t
    on r.type = t.type
inner join TABLE_C l
    on t.type = l.type;
```

The above version is considered the "correct" way of expressing your logic.  Explicit joins solved a number of problems inherent with implicit joins.  Implicit joins place both the join logic and the filter criteria into the same `WHERE` clause, potentially making it difficult to tease apart what is happening there.  In addition, it was harder to express left/right/inner/cross join using the implicit syntax, with different vendors sometimes having different syntax.  The ANSI-92 explicit join is pretty much the same across all the major SQL vendors at this point.